How does PieCloudDB detect if there is a deadlock?
I would like to know if PieCloudDB Database has a deadlock detection mechanism. What parameter settings can be used to turn on the deadlock detection function? Or what views can I use to check the status of transactions and locks?

PieCloudDB Database uses deadlock_timeout parameter to set the time interval for deadlock detection. The default value is 1s. If a deadlock is detected, it will break the deadlock by canceling one or more backend processes related to the latest transaction.
In addition, you can also use pg_locks and pg_stat_activity views to check the lock wait status.
For example:
SELECT * FROM pg_locks pl
 JOIN pg_stat_activity ps ON pl.pid = ps.pid
WHERE NOT granted;

